# memcmp multiple BYTEs, not finding address

Tags: c++

Im trying to memcmp multiple BYTE's from ASM Instructions but my scanner keeps coming up with nothing. The returning value from my function indicates that the BYTEs are not being found.

Called with

```
const BYTE Pattern[] = {0x33,0xC0,0xF2,0xAE};
DWORD Address = FindPattern(Pattern,sizeof(Pattern));
```

Function(Shortend)

```
DWORD FindPattern(const BYTE* Pattern,SIZE_T PatternSize)
{
    ...
    for(int i = 0;i < (ModuleSize - PatternSize);i++)
    {
        if(memcmp((void*)(ModuleBase + i),Pattern,PatternSize) == 0)
            return ModuleBase + i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the byte ordering (endianness?)

Comment: you'd rather improve your original question than re-post bits of your challenge over and over again

Answer (score 3):

As I [replied in your previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18541099/868014), you code worked perfectly fine when i ran it. I tested it against the previous FindPattern function i was using, and both returned the same exact results.

Make sure you have the correct pattern. Its not your function that is failing, its simply not finding what you are looking for.